# CoffeeScript breakpoints not hit when debugging angularjs / jasmine unit tests in webstorm 7

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript, jasmine, webstorm

I am successfully unit testing my coffeescript / angularjs code using karma / jasmine.

One of my tests is failing and so I would like to place breakpoints in my coffeescript code.

I understand that I will need to provide source-maps to allow WebStorm 7 to correlate the transpiled javascript to the original coffeescript (see karma config below).

These questions were useful to get me started but have not completely solved the problem:

- [webstorm 7/karma server looking for wrong sourcemap file when debugging coffeescript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19200570/776476)
- [Using Karma-runner with AngularJS, Jasmine, CoffeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17601744/776476)

Now, when I debug, any coffeescript file that has a breakpoint in it will suspend but not on the breakpoint, typically on the first line of the file or the function that contains the breakpoint.

[image]

Continuing the execution simply runs to the end and the inner breakpoint is not hit.

Attempting to step through the coffeescript takes me into the jasmine.js code. As I continue to step-through the jasmine code the test suite eventually completes but the breakpoint is never hit.

Here is the relevant portion of my karma config.

**karma.config.js**

```
files: [
        'App.UnitTests/lib/http_ajax.googleapis.com_ajax_libs_angularjs_1.2.0-rc.2_angular.js',
        'App.UnitTests/lib/http_ajax.googleapis.com_ajax_libs_angularjs_1.2.0-rc.2_angular-sanitize.js',
        'App.UnitTests/lib/http_angular-ui.github.io_ui-router_release_angular-ui-router.js',
        'App.UnitTests/lib/http_ajax.googleapis.com_ajax_libs_angularjs_1.2.0-rc.2__angular-mocks.js',
        'App.FrontEnd/coffee/**/*.coffee',
        'App.UnitTests/tests/**/*.spec.coffee'
    ],

    preprocessors : {
        'App.FrontEnd/coffee/**/*.coffee':'coffee',
        'App.UnitTests/tests/**/*.spec.coffee':'coffee'
    },

    coffeePreprocessor: {
        options: { bare: true, sourceMap: true },
        transformPath: function ( path ) { return path.replace( /.js$/, '.coffee' ); }
    },
```

Comment: Same for me. I've logged the [ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-9837) for that, please feel free to vote. May be related to Google bug: [breakpoint resolved to incorrect location](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=304150#makechanges)

Comment: I have starred and commented on both the chromium and jetbrains issues. Hopefully there will be a resolution soon.